# Rails - Adding additional item field in form (as collections)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am trying to have the user be able to select additional items instead of one item like how the code below does.

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, remote: true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
    .......other order entries goes here ........
    <h3>Items</h3>

    <%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Choose an item", input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>

    <div class="product">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="price"></div>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery & Ajax RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=comments) has helped me with this, checkout the [repo](https://github.com/railscasts/136-jquery-ajax-revised)