# Rails - storing values - through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, simple-form

I would like to store values in `:quantity` from the table below using the orders form but I am not sure how to do so for this specific table.

```
 create_table "order_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.integer  "order_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "quantity"
    t.decimal  "price"
  end
```

The relationships are as follows

#### order model

```
has_many :order_items
has_many :items, :through => :order_items
```

#### item model

```
has_many :order_items
has_many :orders, :through => :order_items
```

#### OrderItem model

```
belongs_to :item
belongs_to :order
```

Comment: have you took a look to nested forms?

Comment: Unrelated to your question but felt I should point out a massive (and common) flaw in your logic. items should be used purely as a lookup and not directly related to orders. You should "copy" the chosen item data to the order_item record rather than associate the item to the order_item. this allows you to update item data and optionally rather than compulsorily apply the update to historically completed orders.

Comment: @jamesw What do you mean about this? I can see how this would work, and wouldn't affect items, except for reference?

Comment: If any detail changes on an item record, that change would be reflected on all items that have previously been purchased which is wrong. If you look at an order item that was purchased 2 years ago you need to see the description and wording of that item at the time, not what it states now. so it is good practice and indeed a requirement for some organisations, plus provides an audit trail, to "copy" the lookup data to the order_item at time of purchase.

Comment: @jamesw, good insight, I shall make the modifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and then use a [`nested form`](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1) in Rails:

```
#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :order_items
   has_many :items, :through => :order_items

   accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items
end
```

This will mean you will have to `build` the `order_item` object *before* you send the data so your form can use the `f.fields_for` method to handle the associative data, like this:

```
#app/controllers/orders_controller.rb
Class OrdersController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @order = Order.new
      @order.order_items.build
   end

   def create
      @order = Order.new(order_params)
      @order.save
   end

   private

   def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:order, :params, order_items_attributes: [:quantity])
   end

end

#app/views/orders/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @order do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :order_items do |o| %>
       <%= o.text_field :quantity %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I have just noticed that the item id is not registering in the `item_orders` table. I have created a question for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24128798/rails4-table-item-not-registering)

Comment: I got it working. Some other questions: I have not yet implemented the quantity to [affect the total price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121062/rails-jquery-calculating-line-total) yet. I have also not implemented a way to add more than one [item line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063407/rails-adding-additional-item-field-in-form-as-collections) yet.