# rails - jquery, calculating line total

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to take the quantity and multiply it with the price to get the total and print it to #total. And get the subtotal which is located outside of the partial items form shown below.

#### items form partial from an orders form

```
<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered example'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="item" class="col-md-3">     
          <%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, placeholder: 'Item Name', input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>
        </td>
        <td id="price"></td>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_items do |o| %>
          <td class="col-md-2"><%= o.input :quantity, input_html: { id: 'quantity' } %></td>
        <% end %>
        <td id="total" class="col-md-1"></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

#### js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#client-select2").select2();
  $("#item-select2").select2();

  $("#item-select2").click(function() {
    var selectedItem, total;
    selectedItem = $(this);
    if (selectedItem.val() !== null) {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/items.json",
        data: { selectedItem: "[" + selectedItem.val() + "]" },
        dataType: "json"
      }).done(function(data) {
        //console.log(data[1]);
        var i, j;
        i = 0;
        j = 0;
        while (i < selectedItem.val().length) {
         while (j < data.length) {
          if (String(selectedItem.val()[i]) === String(data[j].id)) {
            $("#item").html(data[j].name);
            $("#price").html(data[j].price);
            total = parseFloat(data[j].price).toFixed(2);
          }
            ++j;
         }
         ++i;
        }
      $("#total").html(total);
      return
     }); // end of function(data)
    } else {
        $("#item").html("");
        $("#price").html("");
        $("#total").html("");
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery & Ajax RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised?view=comments) has helped me with this, checkout the [repo](https://github.com/railscasts/136-jquery-ajax-revised)