# Rails4 - table item not registering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

The item id is not saving to the order_items table, I have used this specific code in the form:

`<%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, placeholder: 'Item Name', input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>`

Am I missing something for it to save the id of which item is selected. No errors come up after submitting the form.

#### #Models

```
#models/order.html.erb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :client

    has_many :order_items
    has_many :items, :through => :order_items
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :order_items, :allow_destroy => true
end

#models/item.html.erb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :order_items
    has_many :orders, :through => :order_items
end

#models/order_item.html.erb
class OrderItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :item
    belongs_to :order
end
```

#### #Contollers

```
#controllers/orders_controller.rb snippet
def new
    @order = Order.new
    @order.order_items.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    @order.user_id = current_user.id
    @order.status = TRUE

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

#### #Views

```
#view/orders/_form.html.erb
<% do_ajax = false unless (defined? do_ajax) %>
<%= compact_form_for(@order, remote: do_ajax) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="row form-inputs">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <%= f.association :client, collection: Client.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: "Client Name", required: true, input_html: { id: 'client-select2' } %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div class="row form-inputs">

    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div id="items">
        <%= render 'orders/items_form', :f => f %>
      </div>
    <div class="btn btn-success">
      <i class="icon-plus"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="text-right text-contrast subtotal">

    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
      <%= f.input :memo, placeholder: 'Notes' %>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>


#view/orders/_items_form.html.erb
<table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="item" class="col-md-3">     
          <%= f.association :items, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, placeholder: 'Item Name', input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>
        </td>
        <td id="price"></td>
        <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_items do |o| %>
          <td class="col-md-2"><%= o.input :quantity, input_html: { id: 'quantity' } %></td>
          <td id="total" class="col-md-1"></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Side note and other questions: I have not yet implemented the quantity to [affect the total price](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121062/rails-jquery-calculating-line-total) yet. I have also not implemented a way to add more than one [item line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24063407/rails-adding-additional-item-field-in-form-as-collections) yet.

Comment: Please reformulate your question, so that it becomes clear what you did and which error you see. Right now I have to read through a mess of code and don't get what your actual question is

Comment: I don't get any errors, if I check the database, the id value is blank. After I submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

`<%= o.input :item_id, collection: Item.all, label_method: :name, value_method: :id, prompt: 'Name', input_html: { id: 'item-select2' } %>`

to

`<%= f.simple_fields_for :order_items do |o| %>`

solves the issue.